# GLSL Compute Shader generates blocky (corrupted?) Worley texture

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, compute-shader

So Ive been following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QOcCGI6xOU&t=1s tutorial on Cloud Generation and tried to implement Worley Texture generation on compute shaders.

The problem is that similar implementation on HLSL of this algorithm works perfectly fine but GLSL one produces weird results. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBCUQ.jpg

GLSL code:

```c
#version 450 core

layout (local_size_x = 8, local_size_y = 8, local_size_z = 8) in;

layout(rgba32f, binding = 0) uniform image3D imgOutput;

uniform float resolution;
uniform uint  num_blocks_A;

layout(std140, binding = 3) buffer points_A{
    vec3 points[];
}points;


const vec3 offset[] =
{
    // center
    vec3(0,0,0),
    // front face
    vec3(-1, -1, 1),
    vec3(-1,  0, 1),
    vec3(-1,  1, 1),
    vec3(0,  -1, 1),
    vec3(0,   0, 1),
    vec3(0,   1, 1),
    vec3(1,  -1, 1),
    vec3(1,   0, 1),
    vec3(1,   1, 1),

    vec3(-1, -1, 0),
    vec3(-1,  0, 0),
    vec3(-1,  1, 0),
    vec3(0,  -1, 0),
    vec3(0,   1, 0),
    vec3(1,  -1, 0),
    vec3(1,   0, 0),
    vec3(1,   1, 0),

    vec3(-1, -1, -1),
    vec3(-1,  0, -1),
    vec3(-1,  1, -1),
    vec3(0,  -1, -1),
    vec3(0,   0, -1),
    vec3(0,   1, -1),
    vec3(1,  -1, -1),
    vec3(1,   0, -1),
    vec3(1,   1, -1)


};


float max_component(vec3 vec) {
    return max(vec.x, max(vec.y, vec.z));
}

float min_component(vec3 vec) {
    return min(vec.x, min(vec.y, vec.z));
}


float Worley( uint num_blocks, vec3 pos) {

    vec3 block_pos = floor(pos * num_blocks);
    float min_distance_square = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++){
        vec3 neighbor_block_pos = block_pos + offset[i];

        if (min_component(neighbor_block_pos) == -1 || max_component(neighbor_block_pos) == num_blocks) {
            vec3 wrap_block_pos = mod(neighbor_block_pos + num_blocks, num_blocks);
            int  wrap_block_id  = int(wrap_block_pos.x + num_blocks * (wrap_block_pos.y + num_blocks * wrap_block_pos.z));

            vec3 wrap_point  =  points.points[wrap_block_id];
            
            for (int j = 0; j < 27; j++){
                vec3 distance_vector = pos - (wrap_point + offset[j]);
                min_distance_square = min(min_distance_square, dot(distance_vector, distance_vector));
            }
        }
        else {
            int  neighbor_block_id       = int(neighbor_block_pos.x + num_blocks * (neighbor_block_pos.y + num_blocks * neighbor_block_pos.z));
            vec3 neighbor_block_point    = points.points[neighbor_block_id];
            vec3 distance_vector         = pos - neighbor_block_point;
            min_distance_square          = min(min_distance_square, dot(distance_vector, distance_vector));
        }

    }

    return sqrt(min_distance_square);
}

void main() {
    vec4 value = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    ivec3 texelCoord = ivec3(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xyz);
    
    float u = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x / resolution;
    float v = gl_GlobalInvocationID.y / resolution;
    float w = gl_GlobalInvocationID.z / resolution;

    vec3 pos = vec3(u,v,w);

    float min_distance_A = 1 - Worley(num_blocks_A, pos) * 4;
    float final_color = min_distance_A;

    value = vec4(vec3(min_distance_A), 1.0f);

    imageStore(imgOutput, texelCoord, value);
}
```

C++/OpenGL

Method that generates texture:

```cpp
void GenWorleyCloudBaseTexture(int width, int height, int depth) {
    texture3D->SetDim(width, height, depth, GL_RGBA32F, GL_RGBA);

    unsigned int num_blocks_A = 8;
    auto points_A = GenWorleyPoints(num_blocks_A);

    std::unique_ptr<StorageBuffer> buffer = std::make_unique<StorageBuffer>(points_A.data(), sizeof(glm::vec3) * points_A.size(), 3);
    buffer->Bind();

    compute_program->uniform("num_blocks_A", num_blocks_A);
    compute_program->uniform("resolution", (float) width);

    compute_program->Dispatch(texture3D.get(), width/8 , height/8, depth/8, GL_RGBA32F);
}
```

Dispatch method of compute shader class

```cpp
void Dispatch(tex3D* t, int num_groups_x, int num_groups_y, int num_groups_z, GLuint internalFormat = GL_RGBA32F) {
    use();
    glBindImageTexture(0, t->ogl_texture_3D, 0, GL_TRUE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, internalFormat);
    glDispatchCompute((unsigned int)num_groups_x, (unsigned int)num_groups_y, (unsigned int)num_groups_z);
    
    glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);
}
```

Comment: It seems obvious to me that some of the blocks aren't seeing some of the points. I notice there are 28 offsets but i and j only loop 27 times. I don't understand why there is another loop when it wraps, but the problem still occurs in the middle of the image so I suppose wrapping is not the problem (unless we are looking at an edge slice of the 3D texture you are generating?)

Comment: another possibility is the blocks are somehow out of order